# How to target a pair of values whenever they come one after the other in an array?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to do something that many of you probably will find simple but I am struggling a bit to figure out.

Example:

```
var colours = [red, brown, yellow, black, white, brown, yellow, green, blue, brown, yellow];
```

Whenever `brown` is immediately before `yellow` do something. Or whenever `yellow` comes immediately after `brown` do something.

Comment: Do a for loop, and use `colours[i]` and `colours[i - 1]`

Comment: Thank you. Like loop, and then, `if colours[i] === 'yellow' && colours[i-1] === 'brown'` do something. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes great! In this case it would be checking if yellow follows brown. Don't forget to start the loop at `i = 1` so that you don't get an exception because index out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap this in a function which takes the array, a pair of items to find, and a callback function to execute each time the pair is found in the array.

```js
var colors = ['red', 'brown', 'yellow', 'black', 'white', 'brown', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'brown', 'yellow'];

handlePair(colors, ['brown', 'yellow'], () => {
  console.log('yellow follows brown');
});

handlePair(colors, ['green', 'blue'], () => {
  console.log('blue follows green');
});

function handlePair(array, pair, callback) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === pair[1] && array[i - 1] === pair[0]) {
      callback();
    }
  }
}
```